# Unable to send streams via SocketIO NodeJS

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, socket.io, node-streams

as the title implies I am trying to send streams of data through SocketIO sockets.

I am writing a Node TS application that may need to send large files so the default `Buffer` object isn't enough.

So far I have this code:

Client Side

```
socket.emit("upload", file.stream(), (response:any) => {
    console.log(response);
})
```

Server side

```
socket.on("upload", (data, callback) => {
    console.log(data)
})
```

The connection between the client and server is working, however when uploading files the server receives and empty object instead of the stream. But there's no error appearing in neither the front end or back end codes.

Any ideas on how to send stream through SocketIO? I have looked into `socket.io-stream` but I haven't managed to make it work with ES modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write an example for you with `socket.io-stream`:

server.ts:

```
import * as path from 'path';
import * as http from 'http';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import { Server } from 'socket.io';
import * as ss from 'socket.io-stream';

const httpServer = http.createServer();
const io = new Server(httpServer);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  ss(socket).on('upload', (stream, data) => {
    const filename = path.basename(data.name);
    stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`./${filename}`));
    stream.on('end', () => {
      socket.emit('completed', 'upload completed');
    });
  });
});

httpServer.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('port:3000');
});
```

client.ts:

```
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';
import * as ss from 'socket.io-stream';
import * as fs from 'fs';

const socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
const filePath = '../../../README.md'; //file path
const file = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
const stream = ss.createStream();

ss(socket).emit('upload', stream, { name: filePath.split('/').pop() });
file.pipe(stream);

socket.on('completed', (message) => {
  console.log(message);
});
```

so, I think this example can help you.

Comment: thank you very much! i think i may have a problem with my `socket.io-stream` installation since it's telling me it can't find a declaration file for the module. I tried deleting node_modules and reinstalling everything but that didn't change anything.
Also my client is a Vue3 app so the import is throwing me warns about `stream`, `events` and `util` being externalised so i guess socket.io-stream won't be good for my use case ?

Comment: @JohanDaniel，I'm not very familiar with Vue, but in general this problem can be solved by creat a `declarations.d.ts` file in your TypeScript project and adding the `declarations module 'socket.io-stream'`

Comment: thank you, the import error went away. I think `socket.io-stream` uses the native node `stream` and `events` modules under the hood though unfortunately, which seems to make it not work in browsers

Comment: ok so looking more into it, `socket.io-stream` does work on the browser however now my code is telling me `ss.createStream() is not a function`